# How to create RESTful in apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Here is how I tried creating web service in apex oracle.

**1st Step:**

Creating RESTful services First got to SQL Workshop ->
    RESTful Services ->  Create and fill the form.

[image]

2nd Step: Apply changes.
[image]

3rd Step: Webservices References.

Got to Application Builder -> ApplicationName -> Shared Components ->WebServices References -> Create.

[image]

4th Step. Filled up the form 
[image]

5th Step : [image]

6. 6th Step
   [image]
7. 7th Step
   [image]

   8th Step
   [image]

   9th Step: Created
   [image]

   10th Step: Testing. But it shows an error.
   [image]

After all of the above steps, I was unable to call the webservice from my browser. Please help me in this matter.

Comment: Only steps 1-2 are needed. Steps 3-9 are for **consuming** a web service on a different server from Apex, and are irrelevant here. Try browsing to http://192.168.0.44:7778/apex/SYMPSYS/testService - your URL from Step 2.

Comment: Also on the page for step 2 there should be a "Test" button which will show you the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ORDS with this schema?
If you do something like

```
   ords.enable_schema(p_enabled               => TRUE,
                      p_schema                => user,
                      p_url_mapping_type      => 'BASE_PATH',
                      p_url_mapping_pattern   => some_path,
                      p_auto_rest_auth        => FALSE);
```

then default mapping in APEX can be changed to mapping from this call.